# How to handle two map view in one xib?

Tags: ios, google-maps, xib

Is it possible that one xib having two map view ? If it is possible how to show different data on each map view? I search a lot but can not find any link.

```
if (myMapviewLala.tag==1) {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    coordinate.latitude = place.longitude;
    coordinate.longitude = place.longitude;
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate2,1000,1000);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustRegion = [myMapviewLala regionThatFits:region];
    [myMapviewLala setRegion:adjustRegion animated:YES];
    [annotationPoint setCoordinate:coordinate];
    [myMapviewLala addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
    }
if (myMapviewBNI.tag==0) {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    coordinate.latitude = 51.638373;
    coordinate.longitude = -0.46944;
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate,15000,15000);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustRegion = [myMapviewBNI regionThatFits:region];
    [myMapviewBNI setRegion:adjustRegion animated:YES];
    [annotationPoint setCoordinate:coordinate];
    [myMapviewBNI addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
    }
```

Comment: Just some thoughts: 1. Why don't you use tags for distinguish each map ? 2. Why don't you use different delegates for each map ?

Comment: each map has its own iboutlet and both maps having delegate

Comment: Please add your code in the question and not in the comment.

Comment: Check the latitude and longitude of coordinate2 in myMapviewLala.tag==1..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can show two maps on single view. you can use different outlets and tags to access on viewcontroller.

Muhammad Usman

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can handle two maps in same xib.

Just give different **IBOutlets** for two mapview.

And show corresponding locations on different maps.

Comment: MKCoordinateRegion region;
    
    
    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    
    
    coordinate.latitude = 51.638373;
    coordinate.longitude = -0.46944;
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate,15000,15000);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustRegion = [myMapviewBNI regionThatFits:region];
    [myMapviewBNI setRegion:adjustRegion animated:YES];
    [annotationPoint setCoordinate:coordinate];
    [myMapviewBNI addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
    
this is for one map view

Comment: coordinate.latitude = place.longitude;
    coordinate.longitude = place.longitude;
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate2,1999000,1999000);

 adjustRegion = [myMapviewLala regionThatFits:region];
    [myMapviewLala setRegion:adjustRegion animated:YES];
    [annotationPoint setCoordinate:coordinate];
    [myMapviewLala addAnnotation:annotationPoint];

Comment: Don't try to stuff a bunch of code in a comment.  Edit your original question and add the code there, with proper formatting.